# Strange symbols at the end of md5sum

Tags: macos, unix, timestamp, uuid, md5sum

I've installed `md5sum` on MacOSX with:

```
brew install md5sha1sum
```

And when I tried to create a hash on the terminal:

```
timestamp=$(date +%m%d%Y%H%M%S)
UUID="$(echo -n "$timestamp" | md5sum )"
echo $UUID
```

There's some sort of strange `-` symbols at the end of the hash:

[out]:

```
20e220c825391b96359a7093c33e9f18 -
```

**Why is that happening? How to get rid of the string tailing symbols?**

I could do this:

```
timestamp=$(date +%m%d%Y%H%M%S)
UUID="$(echo "$timestamp" | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1)"
echo $UUID
```

But is post-processing the string the only way to get rid of the strange symbols?

Comment: Why do you need `md5sum`, why not use the built-in `md5` utility?

Comment: Cos the script will end up on a linux machine =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `md5sum` to calculate a MD5 hash from stdin (standard in) it outputs `-` as the filename. For example,

```
$ md5sum hello.c
ff585184df1b2b93e8e67058e1e708c4  hello.c
$ md5sum < hello.c
ff585184df1b2b93e8e67058e1e708c4  -
```

Note that the second command reads from stdin while the first reads directly from `hello.c`

If you don't want the filename, you could pipe the output to `awk` - like

```
$ md5sum < hello.c | awk '{print $1}'
ff585184df1b2b93e8e67058e1e708c4
```

Or, for your specific case,

```
UUID="$(echo -n "$timestamp" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Or,

```
UUID="$(printf $timestamp | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX land, `-` is often a placeholder filename meaning "standard input" or "standard output". In this case it means standard input, because you piped data into md5sum.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing the result use `printf` perhaps, and set the maximum length:

```
printf "%.32s\n" "$UUID"
```

Since `md5` is always 32 characters long using a format string should work.